# Set up PhpStorm+Vagrant+Xdebug

Tags: vagrant, phpstorm, xdebug

I've already banged my head to the wall trying to set up debug process on Vagrant virtual machine.
I've got Windows 8.1 on my host machine and Ubuntu 14 onthe guest machine.

Here is my xdebug.ini:

```
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php5/20121212/xdebug.so"

xdebug.remote_log=/var/xdebug.log
xdebug.remote_host="10.0.2.2"
xdebug.remote_port="8000"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=0
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.idekey=vagrant
```

But in a log file I see such message:

```
Log opened at 2014-11-13 04:32:18
I: Checking remote connect back address.
I: Remote address found, connecting to 10.10.10.1:9000.
E: Time-out connecting to client. :-(
Log closed at 2014-11-13 04:32:18
```

Why there are different ip and port?
I've searched around where it can be overwritten, but no luck. In php.ini I found nothing.

Also strange thing: in my path mapping settings at PHPStorm I have slashes replaced by backslahes. I don't know, is it come to a problem.

[image]

EDIT: Here is result of php -i | grep xdebug

```
24:/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini,
47:    with Xdebug v2.2.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2014, by Derick Rethans
767:xdebug
769:xdebug support => enabled
777:xdebug.auto_trace => Off => Off
778:xdebug.cli_color => 0 => 0
779:xdebug.collect_assignments => Off => Off
780:xdebug.collect_includes => On => On
781:xdebug.collect_params => 0 => 0
782:xdebug.collect_return => Off => Off
783:xdebug.collect_vars => Off => Off
784:xdebug.coverage_enable => On => On
785:xdebug.default_enable => On => On
786:xdebug.dump.COOKIE => no value => no value
787:xdebug.dump.ENV => no value => no value
788:xdebug.dump.FILES => no value => no value
789:xdebug.dump.GET => no value => no value
790:xdebug.dump.POST => no value => no value
791:xdebug.dump.REQUEST => no value => no value
792:xdebug.dump.SERVER => no value => no value
793:xdebug.dump.SESSION => no value => no value
794:xdebug.dump_globals => On => On
795:xdebug.dump_once => On => On
796:xdebug.dump_undefined => Off => Off
797:xdebug.extended_info => On => On
798:xdebug.file_link_format => no value => no value
799:xdebug.idekey => vagrant => vagrant
800:xdebug.max_nesting_level => 100 => 100
801:xdebug.overload_var_dump => On => On
802:xdebug.profiler_aggregate => Off => Off
803:xdebug.profiler_append => Off => Off
804:xdebug.profiler_enable => Off => Off
805:xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger => Off => Off
806:xdebug.profiler_output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
807:xdebug.profiler_output_name => cachegrind.out.%p => cachegrind.out.%p
808:xdebug.remote_autostart => Off => Off
809:xdebug.remote_connect_back => On => On
810:xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time => 3600 => 3600
811:xdebug.remote_enable => On => On
812:xdebug.remote_handler => dbgp => dbgp
813:xdebug.remote_host => 10.0.2.2 => 10.0.2.2
814:xdebug.remote_log => /var/xdebug.log => /var/xdebug.log
815:xdebug.remote_mode => req => req
816:xdebug.remote_port => 10000 => 10000
817:xdebug.scream => Off => Off
818:xdebug.show_exception_trace => Off => Off
819:xdebug.show_local_vars => Off => Off
820:xdebug.show_mem_delta => Off => Off
821:xdebug.trace_enable_trigger => Off => Off
822:xdebug.trace_format => 0 => 0
823:xdebug.trace_options => 0 => 0
824:xdebug.trace_output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
825:xdebug.trace_output_name => trace.%c => trace.%c
826:xdebug.var_display_max_children => 128 => 128
827:xdebug.var_display_max_data => 512 => 512
828:xdebug.var_display_max_depth => 3 => 3
```

Comment: 1) Show your xdebug part of the `phpinfo()` output. 2) Ignore slashes for now -- lets make connecting working first.

Comment: The info you have provided so far suggests that you have `xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1` somewhere. Where ? -- that's a tricky question as some distros / setup have 1) separate php.ini for PHP running in CLI and for Apache and 2) may load additional .ini files from multiple folders. For #2 -- check header of `phpinfo()` output.

Comment: I have added data from phpinfo. Strangely, there is xdebug.remote_connect_back=On indeed

Comment: 1) Check header of `phpinfo()` output for list of processed .ini files. 2) Make sure that this `phpinfo()` got via the same way (CLI or web) as your non-working debug (since diff environment may load diff configs) 3) Check your project for .htaccess and other .ini files -- some params can be passed using those files (check `user_ini.filename` option)

Comment: Considering that `809:xdebug.remote_connect_back => On => On` has `On` twice, it unlikely to be local file (as suggested in #3 in previous comment)

Comment: @LazyOne these doubled values tell that there is duplicate configurations?

Comment: No -- it's master + local. Since it has the same value in both, it means that the "local" is the same as "master" -- so look in .ini files loaded at PHP start ("master").

Comment: TBH: the `remote_connect_back` should detect proper IP more correctly as configured value. Why diff port -- no clue, but it cannot be autodetected -- it has to be set manually.

Comment: Once again: how do you try to debug -- via CLI or via browser? If via browser -- then you should obtain `phpinfo()` output via browser as well. The one that you have made before is clearly taken via CLI.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so my problem has been resolved by setting `remote_connect_back` option to `Off`. Important note: I have used PuPHPet to generate Vagrant config file, and I didn't know, that there, in the PuPHPet config file, xDebug configuration dwells. Hence somehow host and port was always 10.10.10.10 and 9000 respectively. So it seems that all configurations have to be done by the initial Vagrant config, not by the SSH afterwards.